# Verify answer from Google calculator using Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I have just started using Selenium IDE and I am trying to open the Google search engine and type in a sum (example 5+7). This will open a result page with a calculator and the answer in it.

So far the test works but when I try to verify that the answer is correct I am getting an error even though it is. Basically I am highlighting the answer, right clicking on it and clicking verifyText. Similarly if I click on the text box holding the answer and choose verifyElementPresent I get an error as well.

Can someone please enlighten me on why I am getting these errors.

P.S I am new to Selenium so I would appreciate it if your answer is kept simple
Thanks in advance :)

[image: screenshot of code and google calculator]

Comment: Can you include the code (test case) you currently have? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Thank you for the interest. I added a screenshot with all the commands used and the google calculator. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about xpath approach. Replace `id=cwos` with `//span[@id="cwos"]`. Does it help?

Comment: I still get the error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because of the latency time.
Just add a **waitForElementPresent** keyword before validating the result.

It Workss...

[image: Screenshot to show it worked for me]

Happie learning. :)